# VB.net Parsing HTML 100 times. Will it work?

Tags: vb.net, parsing

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.ServicePointManager

Public Class GetSource

Function GetHtml(ByVal strPage As String) As String
tryAgain:
    ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = True
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = True
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100
    Dim strReply As String = "NULL"
    Try
        Dim objhttprequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim objhttpresponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse

        objhttprequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strPage)
        objhttprequest.Proxy = proxyObject
        objhttprequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        objhttprequest.Timeout = 100000
        objhttpresponse = objhttprequest.GetResponse
        Dim objstrmreader As New StreamReader(objhttpresponse.GetResponseStream)

        strReply = objstrmreader.ReadToEnd()

    Catch ex2 As System.Net.WebException

        GoTo tryAgain
    Catch ex As Exception
        strReply = "ERROR! " + ex.Message.ToString

        GoTo tryAgain

    End Try

    Return strReply

End Function
```

What I got here is a vb.net code where I parse the website for its html
This function works fine.
The question is this...

1.If I run 100 threads with this function at the same time, Will it work?
2.Won't it affect my internet connection as well?

I don't want to waste time creating threads and codes a hundred times so if you know the answer please advice me on what should I do instead

Comment: I think the question is not if it affects your internet connection(of course) but if the server that belongs to the URL `strPage` will manage this. Why do you want to parse the same page 100 times parallel?

Comment: Let's just say I'm creating a crawler for my business. Any suggestions on how many threads could be enough to not suffer my internet?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see that could cause you problems is the goto.  You retry if you get an error, but there is no way to break out of the method if an error does occur everytime you request the page, causing an infinite loop.  You should put a check in, saying only try again if some cancel flag has not been set.  Second, there could be issues with the number of threads you run depending on how much work each thread must do.  There is a CPU and memory cost for each thread and it could peg your machine, especially if you get an infinite loop in one of them.  Everything else gets a "it depends."  Your pc and internet connection will determine everything else.  There are tools available to monitor this and I would suggest using them to see what works. I found this page with a lot of information, it might have what you are looking for - http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html.  Hope this helps.

Wade

Comment: I have some reasons why I have to add Goto, first is to be able to continue parsing html after reconnecting from a disconnection